# Installing Windows XP on VirtualBox

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine

I installed the VirtualBox on my machine.
I have the Windows XP IMG file.
I converted the IMG file to a VDI file using VirtualBox command line.

How to setup a new virtual machine using either the IMG or the VDI files.
I followed the instructions, but I received the following error:
**FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted.**

Here are the instructions that I followed:
http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-windows-xp-virtualbox-linux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the IMG file you have of the XP Installation disk is to be mounted as a CD disk when you have the VDI created.

look at this (final) picture of the installation:
[image: picture showing mount options]
<sub>(source: [linuxjournal.com](https://www.linuxjournal.com/ufiles/vbox10.jpg))</sub>

Comment: It works, thank you. The only thing is that VirtualBox doesn't accept IMG for some reason. So, I needed to convert it to ISO.